# Is it illegal to air a pay-per-view channel on a free-to-air frequency?

Tags: international

I stumbled upon an article wherein there seems to be an ongoing case on a certain country with one of their biggest TV network as it is currently pending franchise renewal - with only a month to spare.

According to the documents submitted by the one requested a quo warranto petition against them, is that they are airing a pay-per-view channel on a free-to-air frequency.

What are your thoughts regarding this? Is it illegal to air a pay-per-view channel on a free-to-air frequency or does it depend on the country?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not copyright infringement is legal does depends on the particular country, and apparently there is no copyright law in Eritrea, Turkmenistan and San Marino. Otherwise, this could be a clear case of copyright infringement. I say *could* because the party requiring payment is not necessarily the owner of the copyright – is is also possible that the copyright owner *has* given permission for over the air (in the clear) transmission of some show. They may have also granted a license to a cable company, and the license might be exclusive or non-exclusive, but that is about the relationship of the owner to the cable company. Supposing that the copyright owner granted a license to the cable company and not to the broadcast channel, then it would be copyright infringement (thus, illegal) to broadcast that show. But it depends on a lot of details that we don't know.

Comment: The OP has nothing to do with copyright

Comment: I disagree completely. The basis for determining legality is copyright law.

Comment: The question really has nothing to do with copyright. The broadcaster can’t broadcast a show it does not have rights to whether brocade in the clear or essentially encrypted. A broadcast of material they don’t have rights to is a problem if they do charge for it and is also a problem if they do charge for it.